# Most succinct method that takes a single-level hash argument and returns a copy with nil values

Tags: ruby, hash, immutability

Help me write the most succinct method that takes one argument (a single-level hash) and returns a copy with the values set to nil.

#### example input hash

```
{
  email: 'hans@moleman.com',
  first_name: 'Hans',
  last_name: 'Moleman'
}
```

#### returned value

```
{
  email: nil,
  first_name: nil,
  last_name: nil
}
```

Comment: The goal seem contradictory: **clear the values** of a hash in a **non-mutating** way? Maybe you mean return a new hash having the same keys as the original, with values all nil?

Comment: The question is heavily misleading. The expression "becomes" implies that the original is changed. But the previous comments revealed that that is not what the OP wants.

Comment: @sawa, I agree. Patrick, I'd recommend removing term "non-mutating" from the question title and instead changing it to explain more directly what you want, to avoid confusion. If we're interpreting you correctly, a better title might be "How to create a new hash containing the same keys as another but with nil values?". It's a bit clunky, but it's more clear about intention.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about this?

```
new_hash = Hash[original_hash.keys.zip([])]
```

Take the keys of the hash, zip with an empty array to get pairs of keys with nil, and use `Hash[]` to convert it back to a hash.

Or, as @mu_is_too_short pointed out in the comments, another way to do this that might be less tricky to read is:

```
new_hash = Hash[original_hash.keys.map { |k| [k, nil] }]
```

This is a good alternative, credit to @mu.

Comment: Or equivalently `Hash[h.keys.map { |k| [k, nil] }]` depending on how much you like the `.zip([])` trickery.

Comment: @muistooshort, nice alternative. I added that to my answer (with credit to you)

Comment: @muistooshort How is my one? :)

Comment: I think this is a really elegant solution, I'll give it a few days and if I don't see any challengers I'll give you the checkmark.

Answer (score 2):

```
h= {
  email: 'hans@moleman.com',
  first_name: 'Hans',
  last_name: 'Moleman'
}
Hash[*h.flat_map{|k,_| [k,nil]}]
#=> {:email=>nil, :first_name=>nil, :last_name=>nil}
```

or simply

```
Hash[h.map { |k,_| [k,nil] }]
#=> {:email=>nil, :first_name=>nil, :last_name=>nil}
```

Comment: Nice one! I've never seen `flat_map` before. Love that there's always a dozen ways to do anything in ruby.

Comment: [`Hash::[]`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Hash.html#method-c-5B-5D) likes arrays of pairs just fine, so no need for splat or flat_map, just map and be done with it.

Comment: @dbenhur is right. This works just fine: `Hash[h.map { |k,_| [k,nil] }]`

Answer (score 1):

**The answer to the question before it was supplemented with its comments**

```
h = {
  email: 'hans@moleman.com',
  first_name: 'Hans',
  last_name: 'Moleman'
}
h.keys.each{|k| h[k] = nil}
```

But don't forget that there is a more straightforward way to clear a hash:

```
h.clear
h # => {}
```

---

**The answer to the question supplemented with its comments**

```
original = {
  email: 'hans@moleman.com',
  first_name: 'Hans',
  last_name: 'Moleman'
}
h = {}
original.keys.each{|k| h[k] = nil}
h # The hash you want
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I could come up with:

```
def clear_values(single_level_hash)
  single_level_hash
    .keys
    .reduce({}) do |hash, key|
      hash[key] = nil
      hash
    end
end
```

There must be a better way!